# Setting up a GPS TCP server

Tags: gps, router, gsm, tcpserver

I am working on a project where we are using a GSM modem with built in GPS system. The modem has setting to send GPS signal NMEA format to a remote TCP server.

Can someone consult on where should i start when creating this TCP server. If i have multiple units, how do i differentiate between them when receiving the data and etc.

If there are any online links that could help me get started, that would work as well.

P.S. The router i am using is from Multitech MTR-H5-B08.

Answer (score -1):

I started with this video, may be it might help someone else who comes across this question:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ve2LX1tOwIM&t=0s&list=FLjZg3rkhYw7-bIGejAqzlbA&index=2